# Trying to install citadel on ubuntu 

Tags: email-server, ubuntu-8.04

I almost have installed citadel on ubuntu 8.04.  First I added

```
deb http://debian.citadel.org/ubuntu/ hardy main
```

to my /etc/apt/sources.list

Then I ran

```
apt-get update
```

Then I ran the `apt-get install citadel-suite` command.  Interestingly, I get this problem:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libsieve2-1_2.2.6-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite `/usr/lib/libsieve.so.1', which is also in package libmailutils1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsieve2-1_2.2.6-1_i386.deb
```

So it appears that `libmailutils1` already created a file /usr/lib/libsieve.so.1, and now libsieve can't install.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sweet!  I got it.

First, [a bit of reading](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/48910).  Then,

```
dpkg -r libmailutils1
apt-get -f install
```

I'm not sure if this will have any side-effects later, but it seems like a solution for now

Comment: This is actually not a good solution.  It means I cannot use the `mail` command that is in `mailutils`.  When I try to re-install `mailutils`, I get the same "libsieve.so.1" already exists error as outlined above